# iOS Swift UICollectionViewCustomLayout scrollDirection

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

i'm trying to change UIColloectionViewCustomLayout scrollDicretion to Horizontal. I have tried to :

```
let layout = CollectionViewLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

I need get this results

```
[1][4][7]
[2][5][8]
[3][6][9]
```

Now i have this

```
[1][2][3]
[4][5][6]
[7][6][9]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a few links to help you understand what to do.

http://www.skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial

[https://www.amazon.com/iOS-UICollectionView-Complete-Mobile-Programming-ebook/dp/B00CFLTD50?ie=UTF8&redirect=true](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CFLTD50)

[On iOS, can you use UICollectionViewFlowLayout to get a vertical column layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298520/on-ios-can-you-use-uicollectionviewflowlayout-to-get-a-vertical-column-layout)

[UICollectionView - Horizontal scroll, horizontal layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301762/uicollectionview-horizontal-scroll-horizontal-layout)

[Reorder cells of UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719196/reorder-cells-of-uicollectionview?rq=1)

Comment: I hope this will help me. Thank you! :)