# sizeForItemAt method is not calling when using custom layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I am using custom layout for my collection view but if i use custom layout `sizeForItemAt` method is not calling.

My custom layout:

```
public class HorizontalCollectionViewLayout : UICollectionViewLayout {
    var itemSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0) {
        didSet {
            invalidateLayout()
        }
    }
    private var cellCount = 0
    private var boundsSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)

    public override func prepare() {
        cellCount = self.collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
        boundsSize = self.collectionView!.bounds.size
    }
    public override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        let verticalItemsCount = Int(floor(boundsSize.height / itemSize.height))
        let horizontalItemsCount = Int(floor(boundsSize.width / itemSize.width))

        let itemsPerPage = verticalItemsCount * horizontalItemsCount
        let numberOfItems = cellCount
        let numberOfPages = Int(ceil(Double(numberOfItems) / Double(itemsPerPage)))

        var size = boundsSize
        size.width = CGFloat(numberOfPages) * boundsSize.width
        return size
    }

    public override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var allAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        if cellCount > 0 {
        for i in 0...(cellCount-1) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
            let attr = self.computeLayoutAttributesForCellAt(indexPath: indexPath)
            allAttributes.append(attr)
        }
        }
        return allAttributes
    }

    public override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return computeLayoutAttributesForCellAt(indexPath: indexPath)
    }

    public override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    private func computeLayoutAttributesForCellAt(indexPath:IndexPath)
        -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
            let row = indexPath.row
            let bounds = self.collectionView!.bounds

            let verticalItemsCount = Int(floor(boundsSize.height / itemSize.height))
            let horizontalItemsCount = Int(floor(boundsSize.width / itemSize.width))
            let itemsPerPage = verticalItemsCount * horizontalItemsCount

            let columnPosition = row % horizontalItemsCount
            let rowPosition = (row/horizontalItemsCount)%verticalItemsCount
            let itemPage = Int(floor(Double(row)/Double(itemsPerPage)))

            let attr = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)

            var frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 0,height: 0)
            frame.origin.x = CGFloat(itemPage) * bounds.size.width + CGFloat(columnPosition) * itemSize.width
            frame.origin.y = CGFloat(rowPosition) * itemSize.height
            frame.size = itemSize
            attr.frame = frame

            return attr
    }
}
```

And i am setting this layout at `viewDidLoad` method:

```
let itemWidth = 100
let itemHeight = 100
let horizontalCV = HorizontalCollectionViewLayout();
horizontalCV.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)

instagramCollection.collectionViewLayout = horizontalCV
self.instagramCollection.delegate=self
self.instagramCollection.dataSource=self
```

Other collection view methods are working fine like `numberOfItemsInSection` or `cellForItemAt` etc.  But I can't set insets or cell spacing for my collection view.

I tried following code, **below methods are not calling.**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize.init(width: (instagramCollection.frame.width / 3.0), height: instagramCollection.frame.height / 2.0)
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10.0
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10.0
}
```

**Also I tried to set instets and spacing from storyboard also not worked.**

My collection view now using zero for all insets and spacing.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It won't be called as you are using your own flow layout, as a work around follow these steps:

1- define your own protocol

```
protocol MyCustomCollectionLayoutDelegate: AnyObject {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, sizeForItem indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
}
```

2- Add a delegate property inside your custom layout

```
final class HorizontalCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {


     weak var delegate: MyCustomCollectionLayoutDelegate?
     ....
}
```

3- implement this protocol into your `UICollectionViewController`

```
class MyViewController: UICollectionViewController, MyCustomCollectionLayoutDelegate {

    var customLayout: HorizontalCollectionViewLayout? {
        let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? DeviceDetailsCollectionLayout
        layout?.delegate = self
        return layout
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, sizeForItem indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 50, height: 60)
    }

}
```

4- call your delegate method inside your custom layout class

```
   public override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

     let cellIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
     let customSize = delegate?.collectionView(collectionView, sizeForItem: cellIndexPath)

     // use your size ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add in your controller implementation of the layout delegate. (you added these methods, but they aren't called)

So, not only `UICollectionViewDelegate`, `UICollectionViewDataSource`, but also `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.

Like extension, for example.

```
extension YourController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize.init(width: (instagramCollection.frame.width / 3.0), height: instagramCollection.frame.height / 2.0)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10.0
}
```

Comment: I already implemented UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout but still not calling.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `HorizontalCollectionViewLayout` is subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout` those functions won't get called since they have nothing to do with `UICollectionViewLayout`

Please notice that the protocol you're implementing inside your controller is `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`. This protocol expand the `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocol.

So if you want those functions to be called just change the class you're inheriting from to `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

```
public class HorizontalCollectionViewLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout { [YOUR CLASS] }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will post this in case someone does the same mistake as me. I had the private keyword in the method signature, make sure to avoid this otherwise sizeForItemAt will not run for your collectionView