# UICollectionview change item sorting Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a Collectionview(iPad) with

- flow layout
- Scroll direction: horizonlal
- 3 items at Y and 7 items at X

Possible Device-Orientation is only Landscape.

The normal sorting is like this(one page):

01 04 07 10 13 16 19
02 05 08 11 14 17 20
03 06 09 12 15 18 21

But i need a sorting like this:
**act. page**............................next page

**01 02 03 04 05 06 07**  |  22 23 24 25 26 27 28
**08 09 10 11 12 13 14**  |  29 30 31 32 33 34 35
**15 16 17 18 19 20 21**  |  36 37 38 39 40

Is it possible to change the item-position with custom-layout?
I tried to sort the data source pagewise like 01, 08, 15 ... but this dont help if jump to an entry middle of such a page and at all i cannot use sections.

Comment: You can do this with a custom layout. But... how long is each row? With a horizontal scroll there is no need to wrap any lines. Just have one long line. Unless you set some arbitrary length to the row then it will never wrap

Comment: @Fogmeister. Wrap lines allways at the right of screen, means nr 07. Maybe with paging.

Comment: Then surely you want vertical scrolling? What happens if there are 100 items? Where would the 100th item be? How would you see it?

Comment: @Fogmeister. I only want horizonal scroll. My data are alphanum. sorted(items with picture and text).
The reason why i dont like the actual sorting is that we used to read from left to right not from top to buttom.
I updated my question, there is also a following page.
100 items, then i want see the first 21 like above(bold numbers), scroll to the next page i see items 22-42, 42-63 etc.
I didnt show item 41 and 42, this would be empty if there are only 40 datasets.

Comment: Your requirements are contradictory. I cannot help here.

Comment: I dont know what is contradictory at this, but thanks for trying. Meanwhile i found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678474/uicollectionview-horizontal-paging-can-i-use-flow-layout?rq=1. Unfortunatly the solutions dont work.